# How to disable button when value is 'No' in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular5, cell, tablecellrenderer

Below is my code, which is fetching Serial Number as `'Yes'` or `'No'`, I want to `disable` button when value comes as `'No'`

```
{
  headerName: this.translate.instant("sutk.inventory.grid.partNumberView.isSerialized"),
  field: "isSerialized",
  cellRendererFramework: LinkRendererComponent,
  cellRendererFrameworkParams: {
    onClick: (data: any) => {
      this.fetchSerialNumbers(data.itemLocation.inventoryId, 'Inventory');
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my cellrendered:

```
agInit(params: any): void {
  this.params = params;
  if (this.params.colDef.cellRendererFrameworkParams && this.params.colDef.cellRendererFrameworkParams.onClick) {
    this.parentOnClick = this.params.colDef.cellRendererFrameworkParams.onClick;
  }
  this.text = eval("params.data." + params.colDef.field);
}
```

Comment: can't you just use a `[disabled]="yourValue === 'No'" on the button in your template? (adapt `yourValue`with the variable you want)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted does not really match your question.

To disable a button based on a variable value, your template should look like this:

```
<button [disabled]="!isEnabled">Custom Button</button>
```